# Ionic 3 when the App detects a internet connection reload all the img tags from a online resource

Tags: angular, image, ionic-framework, image-processing, ionic3

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I used the [ionic-network](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/). I am able to display a toast when there the user is **offline** or **online** depending on the **connection of the user** which is working great!

Now when I open the app some pages have an **img tag** that is getting a sources from some **api server** or **url online**. I have a **placeholder** in my **assets** directory when the image fails to load the image from the **api**.

Now when the app goes online I want to reload all the **img** tag when a user goes online. I know this can be done using [ionic-events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) but how can I achieved it without reloading the page?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive '[refresh-image]' and call in every image tag. Inside Directive, using Ionic Network you can listen for Network Change, if it is online. You can update the image src property.

```
this.element.nativeElement.src = this.element.nativeElement.src;
```

Comment: so this works like ngModel right? I will update the state of the image or property of that component when a network change is detected and the image tag will rerender that for me?

Comment: Yes. we are re-rendering the DOM.

Comment: I have an additional little question. For example I call an API from some server and that response has an image. I can always use retry right? For each timeout of the request

Comment: Btw can you provide a full example with the html element? Sorry for bothering.